# Type '(value?: string) => "Required" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorType' in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty new to react and typescript. I am trying to create a form input validation but getting this error

> Type '(value?: string) => "Required" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorType'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'ValueType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Below are my codes

// input.tsx

```
interface InputProps
  extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  error?: string;
}

const Input = ({ error, ...rest }: InputProps) => (
  <div>
    <input {...rest} />
    {error && <div>{error}</div>}
  </div>
);

export default Input;
```

// PasswordInput

```
import withValidation from "./WithValidation";
import Input from "./input";

const requiredValidator = (value?: string) =>
  !value ? "Required" : undefined;

const minLengthValidator = (value?: string) =>
  value && value.length < 8 ? "Too short" : undefined;

const difficultyValidator = (value?: string) =>
  value && !/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$/.test(value)
    ? "Must contain at least one number and letter"
    : undefined;

const PasswordInput = withValidation(Input, [
  requiredValidator, //The line with error
  minLengthValidator, //The line with error
  difficultyValidator //The line with error
]);

export default PasswordInput;
```

// withValidation

```
import * as React from "react";

type ValueType = string | number | string[];
type ValidatorType = (value?: ValueType) => string | undefined;

interface RequiredInputProps {
  onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
  onBlur?: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
  error?: string;
  value?: ValueType;
}

interface ValidatedInputState {
  finalized: boolean;
}

function withValidation<InputProps extends RequiredInputProps>(
  InputComponent: React.ComponentType<InputProps>,
  validators: ValidatorType[] = []
) {
  return class InputWithValidation extends React.Component<
    InputProps,
    ValidatedInputState
  > {
    state: ValidatedInputState = {
      finalized: false
    };

    handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      this.setState({ finalized: false });
      if (this.props.onChange) {
        this.props.onChange(e);
      }
    };

    handleBlur = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      this.setState({ finalized: true });
      if (this.props.onBlur) {
        this.props.onBlur(e);
      }
    };

    render() {
      const { error, value } = this.props;

      const firstInvalidValidator = validators.find(
        validate => !!validate(value)
      );

      const validationError =
        this.state.finalized && firstInvalidValidator
          ? firstInvalidValidator(value)
          : undefined;

      return (
        <InputComponent
          {...this.props}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          error={error || validationError}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}

export default withValidation;
```

Please help out

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Here @katniss
const PasswordInput = withValidation(Input, [
  requiredValidator,
  minLengthValidator,
  difficultyValidator
]);